# How to properly configure include paths with simple CMake project

Tags: c, cmake, embedded

I have a CMake project for cross compiling executables for the STM32. The project structure includes folders for the various dependencies required, where the sources and header files are included in those folders. The CMakeLists.txt file to build the project is as easy as setting up for cross compilation and then `glob`ing together the sources from each dependency and user code, followed by setting the locations of all the headers with `include_directories`. Finally, `add_executable` is used to combine everything and build the binary.

I realize, this is probably not the most optimal way to do this (should probably build the deps as libraries), but it does work for now.

The issue comes in with a dep that has many layers of subdirs (lwIP), and the source and header files contain include statements that are references to levels of subdirs in that dep. For example, the lwIP file structure looks like:

```
> LwIP
    | include
        | lwip
            | err.h
        | netif
```

An lwIP source file (or header file!) might include "lwip/err.h". Of course, the preproc cannot find this file because the relative path makes no sense to it.

How should I configure this project such that these includes can be used without modifying source or header files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to get around this issue is to create your own find module i.e. `FindXXX.cmake` (in your case it is `FindLwIP.cmake`) so that you can create `LwIP_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable within the package.

```
set(LwIP_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../LwIP/include
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../LwIP
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../LwIP/include/XXX)
.
.
(omitted..)
.
.
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(LwIP DEFAULT_MSG LwIP_INCLUDE_DIRS LwIP_SOURCES LwIP_HEADERS)
```

With the above find module, your application can cleanly include the package and use the variables that are created by the find the module.

```
find_package(LwIP REQUIRED)
.
.
(omitted...)
.
.
include_directories(LwIP_INCLUDE_DIRS)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${SOURCES})
```

Since your work is related to STM32 & cmake, let me give you a great reference which will be a nice starting point for your work as well.

https://github.com/ObKo/stm32-cmake.git

Hope this helps.